# Can we create databars in google spreasheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Excel Example - conditional formatting

[image: Excel Example - conditional formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but a crude alternative is mentioned here: [Gsheets-databars](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/alxfTwrPjYs)

Use the formula function *REPT* to create a bar graph consisting of the pipe character "|", repeated a number of times based on the value in the adjoining cell.

```
=REPT("|", B1)
```

Comment: Nice alternate Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I searched and could not found any way to do it currently it not possible.